# EA Connector Creation

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am creating a Aggregation connector though Add-In. I am able to create the connector without Strong target end point by using the below mentioned code.

```
EA.Connector connector = signalEle.Connectors.AddNew("", "Aggregation");
                    connector.SupplierID = parentElement.ElementID;
                    connector.Subtype = "Strong";

                    connector.StyleEx = "LFEP=" + strEleName.AttributeGUID + "L;";
                    connector.ClientEnd.Role = strEleName.Name;
                    connector.Update();
```

[image]

How to create the connector with Strong target end ?

Comment: Good question. I have trouble creating that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EA strikes again. Instead of setting `subType` to "Strong" you need to do this:

```
ce = connector.clientEnd;
ce.Aggregation = 2;
ce.Update();
```

Or if vice versa use `supplierEnd` instead. The `subType` seems to be ignored in this case.

Comment: @ Thomas: It working fine. Thank you for the support

Comment: we should have the EA devs visit this SO from time to time

Comment: @MartinGrégoire I think that some of them also look into this, but do not answer. Speaking from my 15 years experience with Sparx  I think I can tell that the times where customer opinion had (great) value have gone since (say) 12 years. Latest with V6 (IIRC) marketing took over and Dante's Inferno came to Earth: "Abandon all hope, ye who enter here". Also, the support guys have quite some understanding of us users. But their influence on the development team is limited. I also had been in the support of a large IT company and can understand the reasons.

Comment: Tom O'Reilly (currently the COO) sometimes answers questions here. I haven't seen any of the other Sparxians here yet.